# How to convert colored TIFF image to black and white using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Silverlight.dll

Tags: silverlight, libtiff.net

I have a Silverlight application wherein I want to convert colored TIFF image with LZW compression into black and white image with CCITT4 compression.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample that shows how to [Convert System.Drawing.Bitmap to a black and white TIFF](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/ImageToBitonalTiff).

You should get what you want if you combine the sample above with [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1964892/249690) that shows how to convert a Silverlight image to bytes.

Comment: First sample is written in C# and I find it hard to convert it to Silverlight code. I am trying to replace Bitmap class by WritableBitmap. Will that help??