# Conversion of a Bitmap to Pixel Array for Microsoft OCR C#

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-8, bitmapimage, writeablebitmap

I'm working with Microsoft's OCR library and am having problems converting the BitmapImage to a pixel array.

I'm making this application for Windows Phone 8, and WriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.ToArray() isn't an option so I have a static function that'll change a normal BitmapImage into a byte array to feed into the OCR engine.

Well, every time I feed it in the application crashes. What's wrong here?

Here is my static class with the bitmap converter

```
 public static class ByteArrayChange
    {
        public static byte[] ConvertToBytes(this BitmapImage bitmapImage)
        {
            byte[] data = null;
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
                wBitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, wBitmap.PixelWidth, wBitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                data = stream.GetBuffer();
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
```

Here is the piece of code in the OCR method that's causing the application to crash.

```
 byte[] pa = ByteArrayChange.ConvertToBytes(bitmap);

            //Here Is he problem 
            var ocrResult = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync((uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, pa);
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: [`RecognizeAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.media.ocr.ocrengine.recognizeasync.aspx) says it takes "The bytes of the image in BGRA8 format."  You're passing a byte array with JPG format.

Comment: `WriteableBitmap` has a [`Pixels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Dbc, how do I make it turn them into BGRA8 format? and for WriteableBitmap it needs the PixelBuffer property, unless Pixels is the same thing in the WP8 framework.

Comment: Did you get your answer? If yes then help me please. Im working with Windows Phone 8 and followed this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958470/silverlight-image-to-byte/1964892#1964892) But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saving your image as JPEG, but I'm fairly certain that OCR library accept RGB/BGRA as an input.
So why don't you use `Pixels` property? It represents image as BGRA array, so the only thing you need is to convert it to `byte[]` array.

Comment: How would I go about converting it to a byte[] array?

Comment: @user2536897 Have you tried to google it first? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1964892

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can you please share lines of code? i cannot convert bitmap to pixel array.

Comment: @SaadAnees http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958470/silverlight-image-to-byte?lq=1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I replaced the code with this ' var ocrResult = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync((uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, ToByteArray()); '

but it gives exception in App.xaml.cs in Application_UnhandledException

Comment: @SaadAnees Make a separate question with all related information there.