# Microsoft OCR: Convert bitmap to pixel array for Windows Phone 8 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, arrays, microsoft-ocr

I have been searching for answer for 2 days but i couldn't. That's why i'm posting it here.
I followed this [tutorial](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.com/2014/08/windowsphone-81-optical-character.html).

I got error `bitmap.SetSource(imgStream);` so i changed it to `bitmap.SetSource(imgStream.AsStream);`

I also got error message on this line. I'm unable to convert pixel to array. Because there is no `PixelBuffer` and i cannot use `Pixels`

```
var ocrResult = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync((uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelBuffer.ToArray());
```

So i searched on internet and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958470/silverlight-image-to-byte?lq=1"stackoverflow.com") of stackoverflow.com. So I copied and pasted the following code

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this WriteableBitmap bmp)
{
   // Init buffer
   int w = bmp.PixelWidth;
   int h = bmp.PixelHeight;
   int[] p = bmp.Pixels;
   int len = p.Length;
   byte[] result = new byte[4 * w * h];

   // Copy pixels to buffer
   for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j += 4)
  {
      int color = p[i];
      result[j + 0] = (byte)(color >> 24); // A
      result[j + 1] = (byte)(color >> 16); // R
      result[j + 2] = (byte)(color >> 8);  // G
      result[j + 3] = (byte)(color);       // B
   }

    return result;
}
```

And then  `byte[] hello = ByteArrayChange.ToByteArray(bitmap);`

```
var ocrResult = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync((uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, hello );
```

I run the code with Device and it gave the exception in `App.Xaml.cs` in `Application_UnhandledException`

Note: I'm developing on Windows Phone 8/8.1 (Silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

OCR documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.media.ocr.aspx) contains part about Silverlight apps.